# Is the Ubuntu Archive apt down

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, internet, archive

I keep getting  Failed to fetch

```
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/autolog/autolog_0.40+debian-3_amd64.deb  Temporary failure resolving 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Is this just me or is anyone else having this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com is up.
But your PC cannot resolve the DNS for it.

One work around is to try and edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add a line:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
```

at the very end.

Another work around is for you to tell your PC where us.archive.ubuntu.com is pointed to.
To do that you can add the following line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
91.189.91.39 us.archive.ubuntu.com
```

I would go with the first workaround, which should solve the issue permanently..

Unless you are somehow being blocked by firewall or router to make outbound connections.

Comment: Do I need to update anything, or run a command after I edit it?

Comment: nothing to restart or edit further, try the command right after you edit one of these files.

Comment: ok I will, I just locked my self out of my server, Fail2Ban and I cannot get to the Physical Computer! #ExtremeSecurity

Comment: It expires  next month

Comment: fail2ban has the option in `jail.conf` to set IPs that can be ignored from all filters/actions, exactly for this purpose, so you do not get locked.. Since fail2ban blocks by IP, you can connect to another network, or use a VPN to access your server from an IP that fail2ban does not know about, and then reconfigure it to ignore your IPs

Comment: ok, I can get in